# Is there a way to set separate voice options for group channel and team channel?

Tags: overwatch

I want open-mic mode when I'm in the group channel and push-to-talk when I'm in the team channel. Right now I have to go to the sound settings and switch the microphone mode any time I join / leave a group.

Is there some better way to set it up? Some hidden advanced options somewhere, config files, anything of that sort? Or alternatively, some faster shortcut than opening the settings each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched but didn't found anything about that in the conf'(and I had already looked for any settings that might be useful) or on the web. You can overwrite the chat push to talk for each heroes but it's not done for groups. So, I don't think it is possible.
I suggest you to make a request about that because it would be useful, the dev' team totally understood the necessity of overwritten keys, and would probably add this in next patch or in few ones if you request it.

PS:
This is not relevant, and you probably already knows it but press P to go to channels selection faster.